# AJAX : PHP login ajax does'nt work

Tags: php, ajax

I have a login form using ajax and a php code. The issue is that is always returns an error instead of logging me into the system. I have spent days trying to find the error but I can't.

php :

```
<?php 
  include 'db.php';

  $email    = trim($_POST['email']);
  $password = trim($_POST['password']);

  $cek    = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user_csr WHERE email='$email' AND csr_pwd='$password'");    
  if(mysqli_num_rows($cek)>0)
  {
    echo 'true';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'false';
  } 

?>
```

ajax :

```
function ceklogin(){
    var email    = document.getElementById('mail').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;

        $.ajax({
            url: 'tes.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {email: email, password: password},
            success: function(html) {

                if(html == 'true')
                {
                     alert("login success"); 
                }
                else
                {
                     alert("login failed");
                }
            }
        });
}

<form>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="mail" required>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pass" required>
    <button type="submit" class="w3ls-cart" onclick="ceklogin()">Sign In</button>
</form>
```

the result of an alert is 'login failed'. but email and passwords are in accordance with the database.Hope anyone can help me out on this one, thanks in advance.

Comment: console.log(html) and mention what its result

Comment: You need to hash your password before saving on db.

Comment: Instead of 'true'/'false' you can use 0/1, sweet and short, also don't put user's input directly in query, Use PDO or sanitize input first,

Comment: When you click w3ls-cart button, does ceklogin() get triggered? (Because there is preventing default form submit)

Comment: Might be a dumb statement but try setting this `<form onsubmit="return false;">`

Comment: You should really use prepared statements and password-hashing if this is expected to work for multiple users.

Comment: first confirm alert(html) if it is true. then try if(html.trim() == 'true').  sometimes blank space may exist

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Just make sure you have a DIV as identified below to show your result.

```
function ceklogin() {
  var email    = document.getElementById('mail').value;
  var password = document.getElementById('pass').value;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("resultDiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  var sentInfo = "email=" + email + "&password=" + password;
  xhttp.open("POST", "YourPHPFileHERE.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(sentInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try adding "===" in your if condition.

```
          ` if(html === 'true')
            {
                 alert("login success"); 
            }
            else
            {
                 alert("login failed");
            }`
```